# Ceiling fan electrical box swap. Conduit making issues

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

[image]

I had a basic light fixture mounted in my garage ceiling. I'm putting a ceiling fan in its place. After removing fixture, there's a square box with 3 conduit connections. I undid the connections and cut ceiling around box. I used a hammer and pry bar to get the box out. It was nailed to the joist.

I thought I was home free until I looked at the new ceiling fan box with the adjustable bar. Box only has two knockouts. I went online and it seems that all these boxes either have one or two knockouts.

What do you suggest? I want to make sure the box I put in is up to code, whatever that is. Thanks.

-Frank

Comment: So your picture is the old box?  Can the new fan mount just be placed next to the old box, and put a cover on the old box?

Answer (score 2):

There are absolutely fan electrical boxes with the extra support brackets that have more knockout holes. You can also get fan rated boxes that screw directly to the joist, either below it or on the side.

If you can't find them at a retail store, an electrical supply store will have them.

Comment: Yes. That's the old box which is now gone. Home Depot and Menards only have side mount boxes that have 2 holes.

Comment: #1 shopping at big-box.  #2 throwing out the old parts before the job is fully complete.   Those are your problems.  Shop at a proper electrical supply house instead.  These have names like so-and-so Electric, most are local outfits, national chains are Greybar and City Electric.